# Latest edited file in a given list SHELL

Tags: linux, bash, file, list, shell

I have some problem - I have a list (in .txt file) of files with directories, i.e: /student/2012/my/Video/hello.php. The thing what I need to do is to get last edited file of that list, but I don't have any ideas how to do it..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say:

```
ls -1tr $(cat filename.txt) | tail -1
```

in order to get the most recently edited file from those contained in `filename.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, is great, but is it possible to get only file name with directory? Because now Im getting permissions, date ant other things...

Comment: I modified the command to say `-1rt` a couple of minutes after the post; you probably picked up the earlier version that said `-lrt`.  Use `1` (numeric one) instead of the letter `l`.

Comment: Yeah, I picked up the earlier version. Now everything is fine. Thanks once again.

Comment: Warning, this will fail if a file name contains spaces!

Answer (score 0):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687568/how-to-find-latest-modificated-files-and-delete-them-with-shell-code/19703080#19703080) I demonstrated a quicksort algorithm in bash. Here's the snippet:

```
quicksort_files_by_mod_date() {
    if ((!$#)); then
        qs_ret=()
        return
    fi
    # the return array is qs_ret
    local first=$1
    shift
    local newers=()
    local olders=()
    qs_ret=()
    for i in "$@"; do
        if [[ $i -nt $first ]]; then
            newers+=( "$i" )
        else
            olders+=( "$i" )
        fi
    done
    quicksort_files_by_mod_date "${newers[@]}"
    newers=( "${qs_ret[@]}" )
    quicksort_files_by_mod_date "${olders[@]}"
    olders=( "${qs_ret[@]}" )
    qs_ret=( "${newers[@]}" "$first" "${olders[@]}" )
}
```

Then, you could slurp the file's content in an array, and use this function to obtain an array `qs_ret` containing the sorted file names, and you'll print the first one:

```
mapfile -t array < files.txt
quicksort_files_by_mod_date "${array[@]}"
echo "${qs_ret[0]}"
```

`:)`

**Remark.** It's all 100% bash! (and uses some bashisms).

**Remark.** This will also work with file names that contain spaces! (but not newlines, of course).

**Remark.** There are no checkings whether the files in `files.txt` exist or not!

---

Of course, if you just want the most recent, you don't need a quicksort. Just this should do:

```
recent=
while IFS= read -r file; do
    [[ $file -nt $recent ]] && recent=$file
done < files.txt
echo "$recent"
```

An hey, it's still 100% bash and doesn't fail with file names containing spaces.